# Scala Generic Array Elements

Tags: arrays, scala, generics

I am trying to write a function that counts the number of elements in an array of elements of type T that pass a test of type T=>Boolean.

What I have so far is:

```
     def countPass[T](elem: Array[T]) = {
        var count = 0
        for(x <- elem) 
            x match { 
                case x: T => count += 1
            }
        count
    }

    //TEST
    println(countPass[Boolean](Array(true, 52, "test")))
```

I'm getting a couple of errors, the first one is:

```
combinators.scala:45: warning: abstract type pattern T is unchecked since
it is eliminated by erasure
                        case x: T => count += 1
                                ^
```

The next error is:

```
combinators.scala:54: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(52)
 required: Boolean
    println(countPass[Boolean](Array(true, 52, "test")))
                                           ^
combinators.scala:54: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("test")
 required: Boolean
    println(countPass[Boolean](Array(true, 52, "test")))
                                               ^
```

I'm not sure about whats happening with the first error, but with the second error it throws an exception anytime its not a boolean. I don't want that to happen because I'm just counting the amount of elements of type T are in the array.

**Question:** How should I refactor my code to fix both of these errors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trick is using `ClassTag`. A better way to accomplish your request is as follows:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

object Main extends App {

  val array: Array[Any] = Array("string1", "string2", "string3", true, false, 13)

  def countPass[Other: ClassTag](array: Array[Any]): Int = {
    array.collect { case x: Other => x }.length
  }

  println(s"countPass String = ${countPass[String](array)}")
  println(s"countPass Boolean = ${countPass[Boolean](array)}")
  println(s"countPass Int = ${countPass[Int](array)}")
}
```

You can read [this](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html) to learn more about `ClassTag` and `TypeTag`

Comment: This is very far from what I initially have and what I wanted to accomplish. However, your solution did make me realize I should have used 'Any' inside of the array parameter.. But I'm still having an issue with the first error

Comment: Since your array contains different types, your array's type must support all of them. Therefore, you should define an `Array[Any]`.

Comment: Make sure that you import import scala.reflect.ClassTag. Additionally, you can read this: https://medium.com/@sinisalouc/overcoming-type-erasure-in-scala-8f2422070d20

Answer (score 0):

So I found out a way that works, but not exactly what I wanted.

```
     def countPass[T](elem: Array[T]) = {
        var count = 0
        for(x <- elem) 
            x match { 
                case _: Boolean => count += 1
                case _ => None
            }
        count
    }

    //TEST
    println(countPass[Any](Array(true, 5, "test", false, false)))
```

The issue was I needed to pass Any into the array because I have different types in there. Additionally, I needed to change my cases a bit and add the default case.

This works perfectly, but I wanted something more like this. This does NOT work because of the same error specified above

```
    def countPass[T](elem: Array[Any]) = {
        var count = 0
        for(x <- elem) 
            x match { 
                case _: T => count += 1   //Here is the error
                case _ => None
            }
        count
    }

    //TEST
    println(countPass[Boolean](Array(true, 5, "test", false, false)))
```

For some reason I cannot do _: T as my case or I get this error:

```
combinators.scala:44: warning: abstract type pattern T is unchecked since 
it is eliminated by erasure
                case _: T => count += 1
```

Comment: To match `_: T` (correctly), you need a `ClassTag[T]`, as fcat's answer says.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the method count

```
def countPass[T: ClassTag](elem: Array[Any]): Int = elem.count{
    case _ : T => true
    case _ => false
}
```

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP wants, which is a `countPass` that counts elements of the generic type T, not a fixed Boolean. If you replace your Boolean with T, you get the OP's error.

Comment: you are right, I misunderstood the question... I've fixed the solution